# Insert different content IF SQL table contains rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert different content based on if a SQL table has Rows. So far the Query will check what the max value of sortingOrder is and then + 1. However this query will break if there is no rows in the table. How can I implement a if statement to check if the table has no rows and then if it doesn't set the sortingOrder to '1'.

```
INSERT INTO faq (question, answer, sortingOrder) 
VALUES ('$questionData', '$answerData', (SELECT MAX(sortingOrder) FROM faq C) +1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you incrementing `sortingOrder` yourself instead of using `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to make `sortingOrder` an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. The database will assign the values automatically, incrementing them for each row.

If you can't do that for some reason, you can check if the subquery returns `NULL` and replace it with `1`.

```
INSERT INTO faq (question, answer, sortingOrder) 
SELECT '$questionData', '$answerData', IFNULL(MAX(sortingOrder)+1, 1)
FROM faq
```